# The uniapp cli run is suddenly interrupted with this error（WeChat applet）

Tags: pnpm, wechat-miniprogram

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GVvX.png)
It's a vue3+ts project created by uniapp，Have to re-pnpm run dev:mp-weixin to get it to work, not sure why this is happening,The location of the code that reported the error is

```
/**
 * Common handler for errors
 * @param {Error} error
 * @returns {Error|Boolean} The error if defined, otherwise the value of the FSWatcher instance's `closed` flag
 */
_handleError(error) {
  const code = error && error.code;
  if (error && code !== 'ENOENT' && code !== 'ENOTDIR' &&
    (!this.options.ignorePermissionErrors || (code !== 'EPERM' && code !== 'EACCES'))
  ) {
    this.emit(EV_ERROR, error);
  }
  return error || this.closed;
}
```